Envio de correos cada que se agrega un nuevo registro en la tabla con app script
Tengo el siguiente codigo como referencia que envia correos, lo que quiero es que cada vez que yo ingreso un nuevo registro se envie el correo de solo ese registro que se ingreso, al momento el codigo envia correos de todos los registros que estan en la tabla,
    //SCRIPT PARA ENVIAR CORREO DE INICIO DE PROCESO PARA EL REQUIRIENTE
function mailActividadRequiriente() {
  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const Application = libro.getActiveSheet();

  for (var fila = 1; fila <= Application.getLastRow(); fila++) {
    const CorreoRequiriente = Application.getRange(fila, 4).getValue()
    const Status = Application.getRange(fila, 13).getValue()
    //const StatusDevolution = Application.getRange(fila, 15).getValue()
    //const StatusKeys = Application.getRange(fila, 18).getValue()
    // Obtener el valor de "Site" en la fila actual
    var siteValue = Application.getRange(fila, 2).getValue();
    var requirienteValue = Application.getRange(fila, 3).getValue();
    //var supervisorValue = Application.getRange(fila, 5).getValue();
    var tipoValue = Application.getRange(fila, 9).getValue();
    var inicioValue = Application.getRange(fila, 10).getValue();
    var finValue = Application.getRange(fila, 11).getValue();
    var detalleValue = Application.getRange(fila, 14).getValue();
    var fotoIValue = Application.getRange(fila, 20).getValue();

    // Verificar la condición
    if (Status == "Aprobado" || Status == "En proceso" || Status == "Rechazado") {
      var subject = "Notificacion del inicio del proceso - " + siteValue;
      var message = "Estimado " + requirienteValue + ",\n\n" +
        "Se inicio el proceso para el sitio: " + siteValue + "\n" +
        "Tipo de llave: " + tipoValue + "\n" +
        "Fecha de inicio: " + inicioValue + "\n" +
        "Fecha de fin: " + finValue + "\n" +
        "Detalle: " + detalleValue + "\n" +
        "Foto: " + fotoIValue ;
      // Enviar correo electrónico con el asunto y el mensaje
      MailApp.sendEmail(CorreoRequiriente, subject, message);
    }
  }
}


Para la ejecución automática de un script debes usar un activador. Google Apps Script tiene dos categorías, activadores simples y activadores instalables. En este caso deberías usar un activador instalable.
Si agregas los registros manualmente te podría ser más conveniente usar un activador "editar" (on edit). Si los registros se agregan por medio de aplicación o API de terceros deberás usar activador "cambio" (on change).
Para que se envíe el mensaje de correo sólo sobre el nuevo registro y no de toda la lista, hay varias opciones, por ejemplo, podrías tener una columna de estado y que el estado sea modificado por el script luego de enviar el mensaje. Esta opción podría ser la más conveniente porque el script sería mas flexible pero también deberás tener mas cuidado, por ejemplo, incluir el manejo de situaciones como exceder la cuota de envío de emails, entre otros.
Lee

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Si los artículos se muestran en inglés, mira bien la página, esta cuenta con un selector de idioma, el cual incluye español.

n es el número de columna donde marcas si un registro es nuevo. Ajustalo según la posición de la columna de tu hoja. Si no entendi mal puede ser esto. suerte!
    function mailActividadRequiriente() {
  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const hoja = libro.getActiveSheet();
  const rangoDatos = hoja.getDataRange();
  const datos = rangoDatos.getValues();

  for (var fila = 0; fila < datos.length; fila++) {
    const correoRequiriente = datos[fila][3];
    const status = datos[fila][12];
    const nuevo = datos[fila][n]; // Columna donde marcas si es nuevo

    
    if (nuevo && (status == "Aprobado" || status == "En proceso" || status == "Rechazado")) {
      var siteValue = datos[fila][1];
      var requirienteValue = datos[fila][2];
      var tipoValue = datos[fila][8];
      var inicioValue = datos[fila][9];
      var finValue = datos[fila][10];
      var detalleValue = datos[fila][13];
      var fotoIValue = datos[fila][19];

      var subject = "Notificación del inicio del proceso - " + siteValue;
      var message = "Estimado " + requirienteValue + ",\n\n" +
        "Se inició el proceso para el sitio: " + siteValue + "\n" +
        "Tipo de llave: " + tipoValue + "\n" +
        "Fecha de inicio: " + inicioValue + "\n" +
        "Fecha de fin: " + finValue + "\n" +
        "Detalle: " + detalleValue + "\n" +
        "Foto: " + fotoIValue;
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(correoRequiriente, subject, message);
      // Marcar el registro como no nuevo para evitar enviar el correo nuevamente
      hoja.getRange(fila + 1, n + 1).setValue(false);
    }
  }
}

